# Sufficient condition for an inequality to hold

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Suppose I want to show that

$$
a\times b\leq c\times d
$$
where $a,b,c,d\in [0,1]$ and $a\leq c$.

Now, we can see that

$$
a\times b\leq c\times d \hspace{0.5cm}\Leftrightarrow \hspace{0.5cm}b\leq \underbrace{\overbrace{\frac{c}{a}}^{\geq 1}\times d}_{\geq d}
$$

Therefore: is it correct to say that in order to show $a\times b\leq c\times d$ it is sufficient (but not necessary) showing that $b\leq d$?

Comment: @drhab actually i didn't read the question correctly. Deleted my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0\leq a\leq c$ and $0\leq b\leq d$ then indeed we have $ab\leq cd$ but your reasoning is not sound.

If $a=0$ then $\frac{c}{a}$ is not defined, so it must be treated as a special case.

Comment: Thanks. Does the other direction hold? I.e., can we say that if $ab\leq cd$ and $a\leq c$ then $b\leq d$ (with all the numbers between $0$ and $1$)?

Comment: No. If $a=0$ then $ab=0\leq cd$. No matter what values are taken by $b,c,d\geq0$.